# Version-agnostic XML deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I have received a set of XSD files from a vendor.  I need to deserialize XML documents generated by the vendor tool into the classes derived from the schema definition.  I'm able to generate those classes from the XSD files, but the auto-generated classes are all attributed with namespace information, e.g.:

```
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://example.com/XMLSchema/MT/Generic/xxx/v1.5.1")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("Instance", Namespace = "http://example.com/XMLSchema/MT/Generic/xxx/v1.5.1", IsNullable = false)]
```

The XML files are similarly attributed:

```
<xxx:Instance xmlns:xxx="http://example.com/XMLSchema/MT/Generic/xxx/v1.5.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/XMLSchema/MT/Generic/xxx/v1.5.1 xxx.xsd">
```

Here's the rub: I need to handle deserialization of different versions (the incoming XML version varies, and I have multiple versions of the XSDs/auto-generated class), but my rudimentary deserialization approach bombs out if the version doesn't match between the XML and the XSD/class.  Here's what I'm using:

```
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(InstanceType));
            InstanceType instanceType;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"/path/to/file.xml"))
            {
                instanceType = (InstanceType)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                reader.Close();
            }
```

I'm reasonably confident that the newer versions are backward compatible (version tolerant serialization), and I can successfully deserialize the XML if I change the namespace version in the auto-gen'd classes to match.  Unfortunately, this is not a sustainable solution, so I'm looking for something better.

Is it possible for me to:

- Maintain only the latest version of the XSD / auto-gen'd classes;
- Deserialize older XML versions into the new class version;
- Accomplish this programmatically in my deserialization routine, with no changes to either the XML files or the auto-gen'd classes?

I figure I must be missing something basic ... appreciate if someone could show me the way.

Comment: No, you are not missing anything... Namespaces are very important feature for XML and two similarly looking XML with different namespaces are considered different. If you just want to map all XMLs to latest version the easiest would be (not acceptable as answer obviously) to rewrite XML to have namespace you like using XSLT or carefully cloning with code and than reading with your deserializer...

Comment: Don't assume the schema are backwards compatible.  Suppose there were errors in older schema.  For example the older schema left out that a property was required.  Your deserializer will give exceptions when the property is not found.  I would keeps copies of the output of xsd in separate folders.  The use Beyond Compare to see differences between each version and determine manually the effects of each update.  Some updates may require you to change your code to fix bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, both of you.  I've implemented support for the different versions, but with use of abstract factory and adapter patterns to provide a common interface for the rest of the app.  Will post the solution here if I can get my head above water long enough to do so.